# Chmod directories in filesystem

Tags: chmod

I uploaded a zip file of tons of PHP files, images, etc to my website. I unzipped it, and now all the permissions are messed up. How can I use Shell to chmod ONLY the directories to 755?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using `find` command:

```
find . -type 'd' -exec chmod 755 {} \;
```